# Wrong result from GlobalMemoryStatusEx() on Windows

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to get total system memory using GlobalMemoryStatusEx():

```
    MEMORYSTATUSEX memory;
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memory);
#define PRINT(v) {printf("%s ~%.3fGB\n", (#v), ((double)v)/(1024.*1024.*1024.));}
    PRINT(memory.ullAvailPhys);
    PRINT(memory.ullTotalPhys);
    PRINT(memory.ullTotalVirtual);
    PRINT(memory.ullAvailPageFile);
    PRINT(memory.ullTotalPageFile);
#undef PRINT
    fflush(stdout);
```

But the result is very weired and not understandable.

```
memory.ullAvailPhys ~1.002GB
memory.ullTotalPhys ~1.002GB
memory.ullTotalVirtual ~0.154GB
memory.ullAvailPageFile ~0.002GB
memory.ullTotalPageFile ~1.002GB
```

My total physical memory is 8GB but non of result is close it. All values are much smaller.

Also, the 'total' values keep changing whenever I execute. For instance, another result is here:

```
memory.ullAvailPhys ~0.979GB
memory.ullTotalPhys ~0.979GB
memory.ullTotalVirtual ~0.154GB
memory.ullAvailPageFile ~0.002GB
memory.ullTotalPageFile ~0.979GB
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You print values to output? Make sure you treat that as 64-bit integers, without clipping upper 32 bits.

Comment: @RomanR. Okay, I edited post. Now I'm trying to cast all value to double but the values are still extremely small.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the part you are missing:

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX memory = { sizeof memory };
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> `dwLength`
>   The size of the structure, in bytes. **You must set this member** before calling `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`.

If you checked value returned by `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`, you could see the problem by getting error indication there.